# Inverting Map<Integer, Integer> into a Map<key, list<Integer>> using Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

Is it possible to convert a Java `Map<Integer, Integer>` `m0` to a new  `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` `m1`
where in the `m1` map to have *key* as *value* of `m0` map and *value* as `List<Integer>` of *keys* of `m0` map?

In other words, this task it is about the inverting *key-value pairs* grouped by values.

I have tried the following:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put(1, 1);
        m.put(2, 1);
        m.put(3, 1);
        m.put(4, 2);
        m.put(5, 2);
        m.put(6, 2);
        m.put(7, 2);

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> personByAge 
                = m.values()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList()));

        Iterator it = personByAge.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + " <- key" );
            for (int i : me.getValue())
            {
                System.out.println("Values: " + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the values in the second map are wrong.

The values should be:

```
1 <- key Values: 1 Values: 2 Values: 3
2 <- key Values: 4 Values: 5 Values: 6 Values: 7
```

But I'm getting:

```
1 <- key Values: 1 Values: 1 Values: 1
2 <- key Values: 2 Values: 2 Values: 2 Values: 2
```

Comment: The values should be 1 <- key
Values: 1
Values: 2
Values: 3
2 <- key
Values: 4
Values: 5
Values: 6
Values: 7

Comment: Can you  provide us what did you get ?

Comment: The values are 1 <- key
Values: 1
Values: 1
Values: 1
2 <- key
Values: 2
Values: 2
Values: 2
Values: 2 it means the List of values are the values of the m map.

Comment: Yes it is about the inverting key values pair grouped by values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is about the inverting key values pair grouped by values

If you want to invert the Map as you've said in the comments, you need to create a stream over the entries of the source map, not over the values:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> personByAge = m.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.toList())));
        
personByAge.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
1 -> [1, 2, 3]
2 -> [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> personByAge 
                    = m.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                      Map.Entry::getValue,
                     Collectors.mapping(
                     Map.Entry::getKey,
                     Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work using `forEach` and `computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> personByAge = new HashMap<>();
m.forEach((k, v) -> personByAge.computeIfAbsent(v, ArrayList::new).add(k));
```

It would probably be better to use a `Set` for the multiple type as there will be no guarantee of order when iterating over the `Map`, and the keys are already unique.

This is essentially implementing the equivalent of `flip` which is included in [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) on `MutableMap`. The difference is that `flip` returns a `MutableSetMultimap`. The following is an example using `flip`.

```
MutableMap<Integer, Integer> m = Maps.mutable.empty();
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(2, 1);
m.put(3, 1);
m.put(4, 2);
m.put(5, 2);
m.put(6, 2);
m.put(7, 2);
MutableSetMultimap<Integer, Integer> personByAge = m.flip();
System.out.println(personByAge);
```

Output:

```
{1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

Because `flip` returns a `SetMultimap`, it is easier to write test assertions because order won't matter on the multi value. For example. the following test can be written for this example.

```
SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> personByAge = m.flip();

SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> expected =
    Multimaps.mutable.set.<Integer, Integer>empty()
        .withKeyMultiValues(1, 3, 2, 1)
        .withKeyMultiValues(2, 7, 5, 6, 4);
Assertions.assertEquals(expected, personByAge);
```

If your source is a JDK `HashMap`, and you want to use Streams, the following will implement the equivalent of `flip` using `Collectors2` from Eclipse Collections.

```
SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> personByAge = m.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors2.toSetMultimap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));

SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> expected =
    Multimaps.mutable.set.<Integer, Integer>empty()
        .withKeyMultiValues(1, 3, 2, 1)
        .withKeyMultiValues(2, 7, 5, 6, 4);
Assertions.assertEquals(expected, personByAge);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.